# PHPWord setValue case insensitive replacement

Tags: php, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, phpword, setvalue

I am using **PHPWord library** for replacing some placeholder text in Word Doc via my PHP Application.

I have to allow users to upload Word document with some predefined placeholders e.g. **${Anchor1}**  , **${Anchor2}** etc.

Now what happens is some users are defining placeholders as **${author1}** etc.

But **setValue** works in **case sensitive** manner.

Is there any method to use **case insensitive replacement** via setValue in PHPWord

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a predefined option for that, but here you could make some [Monkey Patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

You could modify the source method but that's not a good idea because if you update the library to a newer version you would lose the changes.

Instead of that, you could create a new class of your own that extends the original one, and add there a method that calls the original `setValue` BUT it duplicates the params to pass them both lowercase and capitalized.

Here is my approach. I couldn't try it but I think it will work (of course, you can choose some better names for the class and the method).

```
class TemplateProcessorCaseInsensitive extends TemplateProcessor
{
    public function setValueCaseInsensitive($search, $replace, $limit = self::MAXIMUM_REPLACEMENTS_DEFAULT)
    {
        if (is_array($search)) {
            foreach ($search as &$item) {
                $item = strtolower($item);
            }
            $capitalizedSearch = $search;
            foreach ($capitalizedSearch as &$capitalizedItem){
                $capitalizedItem = ucfirst($capitalizedItem);
            }
            $search = array_merge($search, $capitalizedSearch);
        }
        else{
            $search = array(strtolower($search), ucfirst(strtolower($search)));
        }

        if(is_array($replace)){
            $replace = array_merge($replace, $replace);
        }
        else{
            $replace = array($replace, $replace);
        }

        $this->setValue($search, $replace, $limit);
    }
}
```

Let's see some examples!

**Example 1**

If you do this:

```
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessorCaseInsensitive ('Template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValueCaseInsensitive('Name', 'John Doe');
```

Actually you are doing this at the background:

```
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('Template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue(array('name', 'Name'), array('John Doe', 'John Doe'));
```

**Example 2**

If you do this:

```
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessorCaseInsensitive ('Template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValueCaseInsensitive(array('City', 'Street'), array('Detroit', '12th Street'));
```

Actually you are doing this at the background:

```
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('Template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue(array('city', 'street', 'City', 'Street'), array('Detroit', '12th Street', 'Detroit', '12th Street'));
```